# OpenGL ES rotate the world

Tags: opengl-es

How i can rotate the all world by 15 degrees on the Z axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float) width / (float) height, 0.1f, 100.0f);

        GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, -5, 0,   0.0f, 0.0f, -15.0f,    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

Answer (score 2):

glRotatef(15, 0, 0, 1);

http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glRotate.html

Comment: thanks, but not this is the question. i d like to rotate THE WORLD, or the CAMERA on it.

Comment: Put this at the top of your drawing stack, and everything following will rotate 15 degrees around the z axis.